# Django app links not working in production using Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have pushed my app to a production build using Heroku and since I was previously logged in, I am taken to my home page as my current user, however if I go to logout it re-renders the homepage and I get a messages.error of 'User does not exist'. The app can be found at https://micro-blog-site.herokuapp.com and other details can be found below.

**EDIT**: I was able to logout through the admin app and it appears that neither the login, or register links work.

**Here are the Heroku logs when clicking Logout**

```
2019-05-21T20:45:28.529489+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=micro-blog-site.herokuapp.com request_id=640f08ae-f865-47ac-bb92-5f3cef07250d fwd="174.115.122.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=2532 protocol=https
2019-05-21T20:45:28.433881+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logout" host=micro-blog-site.herokuapp.com request_id=24447334-9a94-4db6-98be-97033077a513 fwd="174.115.122.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=302 bytes=376 protocol=https
2019-05-21T20:45:28.432504+00:00 app[web.1]: True
2019-05-21T20:45:28.435933+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.93.215.14 - - [21/May/2019:16:45:28 -0400] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://micro-blog-site.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"
2019-05-21T20:45:28.531462+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.93.215.14 - - [21/May/2019:16:45:28 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2077 "https://micro-blog-site.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomAuthForm, PostForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Post, User, UserProfile
from datetime import datetime

# Create your views here.

############################################
#
# Homepage view with form to create a post
# and display a feed of post by most recent
# published
#
############################################
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.published = datetime.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('micro:homepage')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error!")

    form = PostForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'micro/home.html', {"posts":Post.objects.order_by('-published'), "form":form, "following":[following for following in request.user.userprofile.follows.all()]})
    else:
        return render(request, 'micro/home.html', {"posts":Post.objects.order_by('-published'), "form":form})


###########################################
#
# Register view with a form to register a 
# user
#
##########################################
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f"New account created: {username}")
            return redirect('micro:homepage')
        else:
            for msg in form.errors:
                for message in form.errors[msg]:
                    messages.error(request, f"{message}")

            return render(request, 'micro/register.html', {"form":form})

    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'micro/register.html', {"form":form})


###########################################
#
# Logout request, redirects to homepage
#
###########################################
def logout_request(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('micro:homepage')


###########################################
#
# Login view with a form for a user to 
# enter username and password
#
##########################################
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomAuthForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect(f'/{user.username}')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")
        else:
             messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

    form = CustomAuthForm()
    return render(request, 'micro/login.html', {"form":form})


#########################################
#
# Profile view displays the user profile
# of a specified user and their posts
#
#########################################
def profile(request, username):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if username in [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]:
            userposts = Post.objects.filter(user__username=username).order_by('-published')
            return render(request, 'micro/profile.html', {"userposts":userposts, "username":username})
        else:
            messages.error(request, "User does not exist")
            return redirect('micro:homepage')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Login or signup to view this page")
        return redirect('micro:homepage')
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'yd@19!!nf4)-4s9(f=y9ou41s2$6g&(#4(*o!4b-zgkeip(^5-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['micro-blog-site.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0']

# Allows creation of custom User model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'micro.User'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'micro.apps.MicroConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Logging

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
             'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Toronto'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
PROJECT_ROOT   =   os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__))
APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'micro')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra lookup directories for collectstatic to find static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'static'),
)

#  Add configuration for static files storage using whitenoise
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

import dj_database_url 
prod_db  =  dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'micro'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
    path('logout/', views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path('login/', views.login_request, name="login"),
    path('<username>', views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

**header.html**

```
<head>
  {% load static %}
  <link href="{% static 'micro/css/materialize.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'micro/css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="{% static 'micro/js/materialize.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- <script src="{% static 'micro/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>-->
</head>

<body class="green lighten-5">

  {% include 'micro/includes/nav.html' %}
  <br>
  {% include 'micro/includes/messages.html' %}

  <div class="container">
    <br>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

</body>
```

**nav.html**

```
<nav class="green lighten-3">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="/" class="brand-logo" style="padding-left: 15px;">Logo</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a href="{{user.username}}">{{user.username|title}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'micro/header.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="row">

      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="col l4 m8 offset-m2 s12 center-align">
          <h2>Welcome {{user.username}}!</h2>

          {% include 'micro/includes/post-form.html' %}
        </div>

        <div class="col l7 offset-l1 m8 offset-m2 s12 center-align">
          <h2>This is your feed</h2><br>
          {% include 'micro/includes/feed.html' %}
        </div>

      {% else %}
        <div class="col m6 offset-m3 s12 center-align">
          <h3>Welcome!</h3>
          <a href="/login" class="col s4 offset-s1 waves-effect waves-light btn green lighten-2">Login</a>
          <p class="col s2"><strong>or</strong></p>
          <a href="/register" class="col s4 waves-effect waves-light btn green lighten-2">Register</a>
        </div>
      {% endif %}

    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'd be helpful if you could post your templates and urls.py.

Comment: Thanks Higor, I have edited with urls.py and some of the relevant templates.

Comment: You should use {% “url_name” %} on your templates instead of hard coded.